# u boot porting on rpi-3: getting error as "cc1: error: bad value (‘armv8-a’) for ‘-march=’ switch".

Tags: raspberry-pi3, u-boot

I am using link :https://elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot.
This is my snapshot:

```
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=/scratch/rpi-tools/arm-bcm2708/arm 
bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-
pranav@abc:/scratch/u-boot$ export USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC=yes
pranav@abc:/scratch/u-boot$ sudo make rpi_3_defconfig
```

upto this compiled successfully.Next stage gives error

```
pranav@abc:/scratch/u-boot$ sudo make -j3
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
GEN     include/autoconf.mk.dep
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18  
warning: unable to access '/home/pranav/.config/git/attributes': 
Permission denied
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18
cc1: error: bad value (‘armv8-a’) for ‘-march=’ switch
cc1: error: bad value (‘armv8-a’) for ‘-march=’ switch
cc1: note: valid arguments to ‘-march=’ switch are: nocona core2 

make[1]: *** [lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

After this I used:

```
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

But then also giving some error.

Comment: Do you also need to export your `ARCH` variable? I think that should be set to one of the architectures in `/arch`.

Comment: ARCH is not needed for building U-Boot.

Comment: thanks. ARCH is not needed for RPi3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CROSS_COMPILE=/scratch/rpi-tools/arm-bcm2708/arm 
bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-
relates to a 32bit compiler.

The defconfig you are using is for 64-bit. So you have to install a 64-bit toolchain and then to specify CROSS_COMPILE to match the cross-building tools that you have installed.

On Debian, Ubuntu, or Mint you would use

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
export CROSS_COMPILE aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

Comment: You have to use aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc --version.  On Debian Buster this gives me 7.3.0 for package gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu. But there is also a gcc 8 package available.

Comment: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc --version gives me :"aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4" 
 But my gcc version is 7.2.0. I already installed "gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu-"  .

Comment: Hi folks,here is a good link for "Porting of U-boot on Raspberry pi-3":-   https://pranavlavhate761157457.wordpress.com/2018/05/14/porting-of-u-boot-on-raspberrypi-3/